# Android submenu: how to go back to previous submenu (or to main menu from submenu)

Tags: java, android, html, back, submenu

Beginner is trying to organize his menu... But I have a problem to implement "Back"-option in my submenus. I expect it to lead user automatically to the main menu. But I couldn't find solution. Did anyone has same challenge before?

I use xml for my context menu:

```
<item
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_sort_by_size"
    android:title="Menu"
    android:id="@+id/main_main_menu"
    app:showAsAction="always">

    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/goto_main_menu"
            android:orderInCategory="1"
            android:title="@string/action_goto"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_directions">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:orderInCategory="1"
                    android:title="New measurment"
                    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"/>
                <item
                    android:orderInCategory="2"
                    android:title="Archive"
                    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_agenda"/>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/back_main_menu"
                    android:orderInCategory="3"
                    android:title="Back"
                    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert"/>
            </menu>
        </item>

        <item
            android:orderInCategory="4"
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:title="@string/action_logout"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_set_as"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

I use following code to display my menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Option click is managed with following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (id == R.id.back_main_menu) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Let's go back...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
        }

    if (id == R.id.logout) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

What should I add to my code to return back to main menu after clicking "Back"??

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **onBackPressed()** superclass of your activity like

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
if (id == R.id.back_main_menu) {
         super.onBackPressed();
         return true;
    }
    //  ...
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

If that doesn't work, you have to give me more informations.
If you use several activities, you could just call the **finish()** method like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
if (id == R.id.back_main_menu) {
         this.finish()
         return true;
    }
    //  ...
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**finish()** will close the actual viewed activity and will navigate to the last known / viewed activity.

**EDIT1**
If you have only one Activity, use **Fragments** to dynamically inflate views into your activity. Look at that example from the developer page:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

**EDIT2**
If you want you different menu items appear, then use **onPrepareOptionsMenu()**.
Everytime you want a new menu, you call **invalidateOptionsMenu** like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
if (id == R.id.back_main_menu) {
         invalidateOptionsMenu();
         return true;
    }
    //  ...
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Furthermore you have to define/override the **onPrepareOptionsMenu** Method in your activity:

```
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    if(mainMenuDisplay)   // If main menu shall be displayed
    {
         // Use the id's of your menu entries to enable or disable their visibility
         menu.findItem(R.id.main_menu_entry1).setVisible(true);
         menu.findItem(R.id.other_menu_entry1).setVisible(false);
    }
     return true;
}
```

Comment: actually I have at the moment only one activity, so finish() or onBackpressed() are bad ideas, they just "close" my app. I was wondering if there is a possibility to "travel" back and forth within a context menu staying in the same activity ?

Comment: are you using fragments? How do you navigate at the moment? Maybe you could provide a screenshot ;)

Comment: I have edited my answer. I imagine **fragments** are exactly what you need. It's the best way for inflating new layouts into an activity, what basically means "navigating". I have added a link above, i have also used this example for my projects. Let me know if this was useful for you :)

Comment: You should also consider to use a navigation drawer. If you use android studio, open a new project and select "Navigation Viewer Activity" and look into the project to understand how this works. This would be the most. Look at this post : http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/add-navigation-drawer-android

Comment: Isn't it another way just to inflate main menu when "Back" is pressed? It sound like easy task, but I'm stuck with it. Cannot find the way to solve this problem.

Comment: I have edited my post. Yes there is a way, although it's not that common, but it works. Save your state, meaning which menu you need, like a variable **mainMenuDisplay** for true or false. Then decide, which items you need to be displayed, using visibility method.

Comment: Okay....my second week of Android programming, and I'm so messed up!..  :)  Thomas, could you give me a hint, how can I save my state to var. mainMenuDisplay?

Comment: Okay...So I played a little bit with the method you offered to me and I understood the idea and how it works. BUT, how can I use it in my case? After pressing "Back" I'll have to press anyway on "MENU-ICON" to open it... And I'd like to link "BACK" and "MENU-ICONpressed"...So after BACK main menu opens automatically. This is my dilemma

Comment: Question 1: How to save state like **mainMenuDisplay**: mainMenuDisplay is a boolean value. Just set it true or false depending on the state of the options menu, you want to achieve. Then ask for the value in **onPrepareOptionsMenu**.

Comment: Question 2: If i get you right you want the options menu staying opened after pressing back. Well i don't know if that is even possible. To be honest, i think you should rethink your menu strategy. These encapsulated menues are not recommended in android, i think it would confuse your customers somehow. A last option i could imagine for you is to use the **ActionMode** of your actionbar, this might be useful for you. But the best way would be, that you use a navigation drawer for navigation, fragemnts for showing your layout and based on the active fragment a corresponing menu entry ;-)

Comment: You are generating brilliant ideas!  :)) Just came to my mint. If I settle inside "Back"-button item's following code: android:onClick="BackClicked", how can I implement onClick listener, which will start context menu again? So main menu would be started by clicking an icon on the toolbar or by clicking "Back" in submenus. Or is it easier to fly to Moon and back?

Comment: As far as i know, that's not possible. Using the onClick method in the menues is not the way of use. Therefore, the **onOptionsItemSelected** method can be used. To open a menu again you could use the activities method **openOptionsMenu()**

Comment: if (id == R.id.back_main_menu) {
            openOptionsMenu();
            }

Comment: Did you mean something like I sent above?  Hjälper inte, unfortunately...  :(

Comment: Then i am out of ideas :-/

Comment: Tänx mään anyway! You helped me a lot. Even if my original problem remains unsolved, I got to know lots of new stuff with the help of your hints.

Comment: Ok no problem. i had similar issues like you when i started android programming 1 year ago. My last advice: Use the android studio templates, when you are new to android. They are (nearly) always working. These templates have some small sample implementation as well and you can relatively easy adapt them to your needs. That's what i did for the start. It gave me a good base knowledge about navigation and using fragments. It's also helpful to read the "best practice" tutorials of the android developer website ;) Even if it's consuming time, it's worth it!

Comment: feel free to ask me whenever you're having some trouble